# How to improve join performance when broadcast variable is used?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Spark. I have two RDDs where one with a size of 9 GB (400 million lines) (RDD1) and the other 110 KB (4 million lines) (RDD2). I use RDD2 as a broadcast variable to decrease the shuffle process. My code works but again for the reduceByKey part it is too slow.

I have been playing around partition numbers. If I set 10,000 partitions for both RDD it starts to spill. So i increased it to 20K, 30K and 100K. It stopped spilling however it is extremely slow. On the other hand, I used 
set("spark.akka.frameSize","1000") but it did not work out. How could I improve this code?

Here is my code:

```
   val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("abdulhay").setMaster("local[*]").set("spark.shuffle.spill", "true")
      .set("spark.shuffle.memoryFraction", "0.4")
      .set("spark.executor.memory","128g")
      .set("spark.driver.memory","128g")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val emp = sc.textFile("\\.txt",30000)...RDD1
val emp_new = sc.textFile("\\.txt",10000)...RDD2

val emp_newBC = sc.broadcast(emp_new.groupByKey.collectAsMap)

        val joined = emp.mapPartitions(iter => for {
          (k, v1) <- iter
          v2 <- emp_newBC.value.getOrElse(k, Iterable())
        } yield (s"$v1-$v2", 1))

val olsun = joined.reduceByKey((a,b) => a+b)
```

Comment: This might just the result of your logic. Your for-comprehension generates tuples for every combination of `v1` and `v2` for a given `k` which could be massive. If you do a count of `joined`, what does that return?

Comment: Also, as a side note, you can replace your `reduceByKey((a,b) => a+b)` with `reduceByKey(_ + _)` for a shorter underscore notation.

Comment: Thanks Rohan. Actually I am aware of the situation that join results are massive. Indeed there are 1.1 trillion as a result of it. However i was thinking that by applying broadcast var and enough sources it might be fast. For ex. i tried emp_new vs emp_new whose join results 11 billion lines and spark handled that within 30 min. And while doing this i used only 4 cores and 20 gb memory in total. Considering this i was wondering is it possible to assign multiple jobs to be run concurrently on the same machine? Or do you have any suggestions to handle this issue?